Setting Transport Headers in MImeKit
I am currently attempting to send an email to another domain. I would like to add in/attach a transport header for the email I am sending. Is there any default way I can set a transport header in mimekit, or should I basically create a custom header.
I tried looking through the documentation, but was unable to find a dedicated method to send transport headers for a particular email.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I don't think anyone (including myself) understands what you mean exactly by "transport headers".
